# Node.js https server (apache certificates)

Tags: node.js, apache, apache2, ssl-certificate

There is a site, let's say `https://foo.blah/` (which served by apache). My node.js app listens on port 8080. When I go to `http://foo.blah:8080` it works well. But when I go to `https://foo.blah:8080` it gives me "This site can’t be reached". I guess, that it is because the node.js app is created with http module. If I am right, that means I have to use https module. So I need certificates. Can use certificates which are in apache2 directory? There are three files with .pem extension. Or should I do something else? Does node.js offer something useful for this case?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to enable Mod Proxy to forward port 8080 of your application on your apache server.
Use the certificates you have with apache.
See how to enable the Mod [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension).

Comment: So I can't do something else? It's not my server, so changing configuration of apache would be a little bit painful (I would have to write to someone, who can do it and hope that he will be ok with this). But if there is no another way...

Comment: You can expose your nodejs server, but you should be careful to use only production settings. It just makes sense to use the apache certificates if you already have a reverse proxy set up. As answered here https://serverfault.com/questions/286960/does-it-make-sense-to-reverse-proxy-node-js-through-apache you may want to use HAproxy or Squid for monitoring.